# Can I play a sound on watchOS 2 using WKAudioFilePlayerItem without a bluetooth headset?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, ios9, watchos-2

I'm making app for watchOS 2 that also must record sounds then show them in a table and you can play each sound and check if you like.

Can I play a sound using Apple Watch speakers in watchOS2? `WKAudioFilePlayerItem` requires me to pair a bluetooth headset but I don't want the need for using a bluetooth headset.

> I just want to play like a sound when a button is tapped! Can I manage this using watchOS 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't play sounds directly from the Apple Watch speaker with any API available at this moment.

Comment: By "at this moment" you mean in watchOS 2 it will not be implemented such API?

Comment: Yes, I don't think Apple will implement this method before releasing the final watchOS 2 version.

Comment: Well..that's kinda ugly. Thank you.